# install z3 in a remote linx server control without being root

Tags: python, linux, server, z3

I am trying to install z3 on a remote server that I am not the root of. I followed the steps to the point where I have this message:

```
Z3 was successfully built.
Z3Py scripts can already be executed in the 'build/python' 

Use the following command to install Z3 at prefix /usr.
    sudo make install
```

Since it says that Z3py scripts can already be executed, is the next command necessary? if so, how can I execute it without being root. Is there an alternative?

I have changed the prefix to a directory that I have write access for. Again, it installed z3 and z3py successfully but then it says:

```
Use the following command to install Z3 at prefix /z3/z3-master.
    sudo make install
```

when I use `make install` this is what I get:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/z3’: Permission denied
Makefile:4462: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Comment: Configure with `./configure --prefix="$HOME/z3"`. You will have a standard Linux filesystem layout under `z3/`. No special permissions required. You may need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/z3/lib` if `configure.ac` does not set a RUNPATH.

Comment: @jww `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure it like this: `python scripts/mk_make.py --prefix=/a/place/with/write/access`

Comment: still the same issue. it says `successfully built`  and then `Use the following command to install Z3 at prefix /usr.
    sudo make install`  and I am not root so I am still stuck

Comment: That’s bizarre. What happens if you just type `make install` in the build directory after it says that? Does it at least have the directory you specified created and populated?

Comment: I have fixed it. now I get : `Z3 was successfully installed.`

Comment: @basel117 Telling people "you fixed it" doesn't help the community. If this answer helped you, you should accept it so others can understand it. If not, you're welcome to answer your own question and accept it so it helps others.

Comment: Great to hear. The proper way on stack-overflow to indicate an answer helped you is to "accept" it.  (See the little checkmark under the up-down vote buttons.)